# IIS7 and ARR as reverse proxy for Subversion

Tags: svn, iis-7, reverse-proxy

I am using IIS7 and the Application Request Routing extension to act as a reverse proxy to Subversion running on Apache.

The proxy works fine and I am able to explore the server, and even perform a "check out". However, I cannot browse to files that would normally be forbidden by ASP.NET - for example, .cs, .csproj, and so on. Files ASP.NET wouldn't be concerned with - such as .txt - are fine.

I tried to edit the global web.config to remove the Forbidden handler mapping for these files, but it did not seem to make a difference. Is there any way to allow the URL rewriting module in IIS7 to work, while allowing all file extensions to be rendered?

Answer (score 17):

IIS7 has an [applicationHost.config](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/124/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig/) file which has a security section that limits file extensions:

```
<requestFiltering>
  <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true">
    <add fileExtension=".cs" allowed="false" />
    <add fileExtension=".csproj" allowed="false" />
    <add fileExtension=".vb" allowed="false" />
    <add fileExtension=".vbproj" allowed="false" />
    ....
  </fileExtensions>
```

More information:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/143/how-to-use-request-filtering/

I added a similar section to my site's web.config and used a `<clear />` node to remove all extensions. Now I can serve .cs, .csproj files and others, but I cannot serve .config files yet.

**Edit:** Removing the hiddenSection nodes corrected this for web.config files too. Here is my local web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true">
        <clear />
      </fileExtensions>
      <verbs allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true" />
      <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="true">
        <clear />
      </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I got it working with my web.config looking like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:8080/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:8080/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://svn.mysite.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_ENCODING}" pattern="[^(gzip)]" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true">
            <clear />
          </fileExtensions>
          <verbs allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true" />
          <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="true">
            <clear />
          </hiddenSegments>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Paul Stovell answer, I would recommend activating double escaping. I encountered errors when retrieving files continaing a "+" character in the file name. Double escaping eliminates this problem :

```xml
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="SVNIn" stopProcessing="false">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8082/svn/{R:1}" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
            <security>
                <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
                    <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true">
                        <clear />
                    </fileExtensions>
                    <verbs allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true" />
                    <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="true">
                        <clear />
                    </hiddenSegments>
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.webServer>

    <security>

        <requestFiltering>

            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" maxUrl="4096" maxQueryString="131072" />

        </requestFiltering>

    </security>

</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).