# Can't commit several files from Visual Studio project to subversion

Tags: visual-studio, iis, svn, visualsvn

Since a few weeks, I have some problems with Subversion. When I try to commit files from a Visual Studio 2017 project there are some files which I can't commit to my Visual SVN Server. To be precise all files in the project folder like *.cs, *.config, *.csproj, *.resx, ...

My setup:
Client: TortoiseSVN 1.9.7 on Windows10
Server: VisualSVN behind a IIS-ReverseProxy running on Windows Server 2012r2

The error I get when I try to commit for example a *.cs file:

```
Commit
D:\Test\branches\ScaraControl\ScaraControl\Form1.cs
D:\Test\branches\ScaraControl\ScaraControl\Form1.cs
Commit failed (details follow):
File 'D:\Test\branches\ScaraControl\ScaraControl\Form1.cs' is out of date
'/svn/Test/!svn/txr/5-9/branches/ScaraControl/ScaraControl/Form1.cs' path not found
You have to update your working copy first.
```

Updating the working copy is finishing successfully but doesn't fix the problem.

You can see my project in the picture below. For testing, I created a completely new and empty repository. As you can see the .vs, bin and obj folders are ignored with all the files inside of them, all other folders are committed to the server (without the files inside of them). In the second picture you can see that I can commit the *.sln file but no other file in the project folder.

[image]
[image]

For testing, I created an empty text file and renamed it to text.cs. Even this empty file cannot be committed to the Server with the same error message.

Due to the fact that this is happening to all Clients, it is more likely to be a problem on the Server side I guess but I have no idea what could cause this error. Unfortunately, the VisualSVN Server has no error logging or at least not the free version I'm using.

I would be very grateful for any tip I can get to solve this annoying problem.

**Edit1: Problem is caused by the IIS Reverse-Proxy**

After connecting via port 8443 directly to the VisualSVN server (bypassing the reverse proxy) everything is working again. So there must be a problem with the configuration of the URL Rewrite module. To be honest it took me quiet a long time to get it working somehow because my knowledge about all the settings is very limited.

This my Web.config with the settings for the URL Rewrite module. Maybe there is something not configured as it should be. If you need further information just ask.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://svn.example.org:8443/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://svn.example.org/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://svn.example.org:8443/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="Users" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="https://svn.example.org" exactDestination="true" childOnly="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: VisualSVN Server logs to the events of Windows. To see the logs you need to open the event viewer from the control panel (computer management) and then select the application and service logs.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice but I already checked the event log. There are no errors or something that could help, only a few logs with service running/ paused.

Comment: VisualSVN Server has error logging in free Standard Edition. If there are no errors on the log, I'd try to research what's the IIS reverse proxy doing. Could be some misconfiguration on its side.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this problem? I'm having similar problems and also run a reverse proxy. Note the VisualSVN browser lists the file but when opening it you receive the error "Not Found". If you connect with the IP address and port, it seems to work.

Comment: Hi and sorry for my late answer.

@bahrep You are right, after bypassing the IIS Reverse Proxy and connecting directly to VisualSVN the errors are gone so it is the Reverse Proxy for sure. I can't see a misconfiguration or something else but I'm not very experienced with the URL-Rewirte modul. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
The fails because IIS prohibits URL suffixes like `.cs` and `.config`

You can work around this by adding this to the web.config of the IIS proxy

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true">
        <clear />
      </fileExtensions>
      <verbs allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true" />
      <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="true">
        <clear />
      </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Credits to this post [IIS7 and ARR as reverse proxy for Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483531/iis7-and-arr-as-reverse-proxy-for-subversion)

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and am running a reverse proxy through IIS, so believe that has something to do with it.

VisualSVN is served up locally on `https://localhost:8443` and I was attempting to use the reverse proxy to route from `https://svn.mysite.com`. This *appears* to work fine. You can even checkout a fresh copy of the repo and all files are downloaded. It's when you try and commit that you have problems - as you've identified, certain files fail to be found on the repo.

The only work around I have found (thanks to your question narrowing down the likely causes) was to add the port to the URL: `https://svn.mysite.com:8443`. This shouldn't be necessary as the reverse proxy should handle, so I'm guessing it's an issue with VisualSVN which may be fixed in a future update.

Comment: Connecting via port 8443 directly to the VisualSVN server is working like it should be. There must be something wrong with my reverse proxy settings. I'll update my question with further information.